# Weird Edges in Blender 2.8 Eevee

Tags: edges, eevee-render-engine

[image]

Hey all, does anyone know why this is occurring and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Please don't post smartphone photos**, use either the built-in screenshot function that Blender has or **the screenshot function that comes with every operating system since the 90s** or chose one of the thousands of free screenshot tools that you can download from the internet. It's 2019, you know...

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it with different light resources, sun instead of spot, larger radius.
Problem:
[image]

[image]

Solution:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a universal problem in all 3D environments. You have faces overlaying each other, and that weird edge is the result of them trying to show up above the other, causing the engine to freak out in that area.

The easy way out is to use a limited dissolve function (Found when hitting X in edit mode.) This simplifies the mesh by removing competitive faces and replacing them with new ones.